# Пропорции в видео

Tags: html, css, видео

Возможно ли как-то загрузить видео на страницу без сохранения пропорций?

```
<video id="video" height="460px" width="780px" src="video/videoplayback.mp4"></video>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтобы видео было высотой 460пикс и шириной 780пикс, если я задаю оба параметра, то размер блока точно такой же, но размер видео меньше из-за пропорций, а если задаю какой-то один параметр, то второй подбирается автоматически.

Comment: Поиграй с `position:absolute; top & bottom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте дописать в стили для видео тега [свойство](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) `object-fit: cover`.